# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' windows using Cpanel

Tags: mysql, laravel, cpanel

I am trying to publish my website through cpanel. when I run the web url of my site, it gives the error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' and my .env file is given below

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:wwuqMKOwBR67OJgHY76xAxEFbCqyKTE/Fd1T25Xfjg8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://salonfurnisher.co.uk/public/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ew3tfqy9_myproject
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=[REDACTED]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[REDACTED]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=[REDACTED]
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Saloon Furnisher"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: where is your db password??

Comment: There is no password for my db @A.ANoman

Comment: execute this command `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @A.ANoman still the same issue

Comment: Please remove any sensitive data from your question... specifically email/password

Comment: It's your local server error or cpanel error?

Comment: @A.ANoman cpanel error when I try to run this url "http://salonfurnisher.co.uk/public/"

Comment: I know cpanel has an user and password must. So how do configure your database in your cpanel??

Comment: @A.ANoman Now I edit my .env file 
**
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:wwuqMKOwBR67OJgHY76xAxEFbCqyKTE/Fd1T25Xfjg8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://salonfurnisher.co.uk/public/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ew3tfqy9_myproject
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=irfan1874242

but still got the same error**

Comment: change this part `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` and grant all privileges of your database

Answer (score 1):

You have to grant all permission your database like the picture

[image: Like this image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to DB with other client (Mysql developer). Make sure db exists. Make sure you are connecting to the right mysql server, not mixing it like vagrant with xampp or wamp (if you have more than one installed).

Comment: I have only one server installed in my system that is Xampp @Peter

Comment: @Irfan Iffi Okay, I visited http://salonfurnisher.co.uk/public/ from APP_URL. This is not local development environment. It says Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `permissions`)  You cannot have user with no password set in production. You must have a password set.

Comment: If your host file has the same url with different (local) ip set it might cause issues. Use different url locally and it is a good practice to use password locally also.

Comment: please look in the apache logs to see what causes the error. Most probably .htaccess or db credentials.